# Permissions missing to use SetSystemTime

Tags: windows, privileges

I'm trying to use SetSystemTime (from Kernel32.dll) or alternatively to use `TIME` from cmd.exe.
Both fail, `TIME` gives me the error

> A required privilege is not held by the client.

I've already used `gpedit.msc` to add local/Users and also the user itself to `security settings/Local Policies/Change the system time`.
I tried to enable the privileg with `AdjustTokenPrivileges( SeSystemtimePrivilege ...)`, but I got a `GrandPrivilege failed` error .

I'm using Win7 x32 Professional.

It's a standard user with admin privileges, but I'm trying to make the time changes without `"Run as Administrator"`, as the program that calls the `SetSystemTime` function shouldn't be started with `"Run as Administrator"`.

I supposed that the purpose of the `Change the system time` policy is exactly for this case and it's also described at MSDN

I'm at a loss what to do.

Comment: You may need to start the cmd by "Run as Administrator", otherwise it is still running without elevated privileges.

Comment: @kennyzx Thanks, but a normal user can't run the command with "Run as Administrator" (In my case it's possible, as the user has it). And the program using the `SetSystemTime` must not started with admin privileges

Comment: So you are trying to enable a standard user to change system time, by editing group policy setting, and by default only Administrators and LOCAL SERVICES can make the change?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes, it's only necessary to change the time without admin privileges, if I have to use group policy settings or something different isn't important for me.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, `whoami /priv` lacks of the privilege `SeSystemtimePrivilege` even after I've added the user to the `Local Policies/Change the system time`

Comment: @HarryJohnston I retested it, only when I started cmd.exe with admin privileges, then `whoami /priv` shows also the SeSystemTimePrivilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that although `SeSystemTimePrivilege` doesn't trigger UAC for a non-administrator, it *is* still removed from the restricted token that is generated when an administrator logs in.  The upshot is that you can use group policy to assign `SeSystemTimePrivilege` to non-administrative users, but the policy has no effect for an administrative user.

If it is acceptable for the program to require elevation when run by an administrative user, you could use the `highestAvailable` manifest setting.  That way, the program will only ask for elevation if the user is an administrator.  Alternatively, you could design the program to ask for elevation only when it actually needs to set the time.

If an elevation prompt is not acceptable, you will have to install a system service to change the system time on your application's behalf.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, i was afraid of such outcome. As my program can't ask the user, I have to write a system service